# I can't figure out MPI_Scatterv and MPI_Gatherv

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I was trying to scatter an 1-dim n*n array  to p processors and then used gather to get the data back.but the problem is it displays the garbage output when i run the program.
i am using an Array A which is of n*n and an array b which is of size n .

```
// num_rows is the number of rows each process will be receiving,base is the base index and last is the last index .
// curr_index_proce is the index of the processor which contains the index i of Array A. 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define NUM_EQN 10

#define NUM_ROWS(i,n,p)  ((((i)+1)*(n)/(p)) - ((i)*(n)/(p)))
#define BASE(i,n,p)     (((i)*(n)/(p)))
#define LAST(i,n,p) ((((i)+1)*(n)/(p)) - 1)
#define CUR_INDEX_PROC(i,n,p) ( ((p) * ( (i) + 1 ) - 1 )/(n))

#define MIN(a,n) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

void gather(float *A,float *b,int n);
void print_array(float *A,float *b,int n){
        int i,j;
        for ( i = 0 ; i < n;i++){
//              printf("i = %d ",i);
                for(j = 0 ; j < n;j++){
                        printf("%6.2f " ,A[i*n+j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                //printf(" : %6.2f\n",b[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");
}



int SIZE_A(int n,int p ){
    if ( n%p == 0 )
            return n*n/p;
    else
            return n*(n/p+1);
}

int SIZE_B(int n,int p){
    if ( n%p == 0 )
            return n/p;
    else
            return n/p + 1;
}
int main(int argc,char **argv){
        MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
        int size,rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(  MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
        double time_start, time_finish;
        float *A = malloc(sizeof(float)*NUM_EQN*NUM_EQN);
        float *b = malloc(sizeof(float)*NUM_EQN);
        float *X;
        int i,j;
        FILE *fp = fopen("A","r");
        if (fp == NULL ){
                printf("Error %s Not Found\n",argv[1]);
                exit(0);
                MPI_Finalize();
        }
        for ( i = 0 ; i < NUM_EQN;i++)
                for(j = 0 ; j < NUM_EQN;j++)
                        fscanf(fp,"%f",&A[i*NUM_EQN+j]);
        FILE *fp2 = fopen("b","r");
        if (fp2 == NULL ){
                printf("Error %s Not Found\n",argv[2]);
                exit(0);
        }
        for ( i = 0 ; i < NUM_EQN;i++)
                fscanf(fp2,"%f",&b[i]);
        time_start = - MPI_Wtime();
        gather(A,b,NUM_EQN);
        time_finish = MPI_Wtime();
        char name[100];
        int length;
        MPI_Finalize();
}

void gather(float *A,float *b,int n){
        int pivot,i,col;
        int row, j;
        int size,rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(  MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
        float global_max;
        float *A_recv,*b_recv;
        A_recv = malloc(sizeof(float)*(SIZE_A(n,size)));
        b_recv = malloc(sizeof(float)*(SIZE_B(n,size)));
    printf("%d %d \n",SIZE_A(n,size),SIZE_B(n,size));
    if ( rank == 0 ){
            print_array(A,b,n);
    }
                int send_count[size];
                int disp[size];
                int send_count_b[size];
                int disp_b[size];
                for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ){
                                send_count[i] = 0 ;
                                send_count_b[i] = 0;
                }
                for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ){
                                send_count[i] = n*NUM_ROWS(i,n,size);
                                if ( i == 0 )
                                        disp[i] = 0;
                                else
                                        disp[i] = disp[i-1] + send_count[i-1];
                                send_count_b[i] = NUM_ROWS(i,n,size);
                                if ( i == 0 )
                                        disp_b[i] = 0 ;
                                else
                                        disp_b[i] = disp_b[i-1] + send_count_b[i-1];
                }
                MPI_Scatterv(A, send_count, disp,MPI_FLOAT, A_recv,SIZE_A(n,size),MPI_FLOAT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Scatterv(b, send_count_b, disp_b,MPI_FLOAT, b_recv,send_count_b[rank], MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                for ( i = 0 ; i < send_count[rank]; i++ ){
                        for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
                                printf("%3.2f : ",A_recv[i*n+j]);
                        printf("\n\n");
                }
                MPI_Gatherv(A_recv,SIZE_A(n,size),MPI_FLOAT,A,send_count,disp,MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Gatherv(b_recv,send_count_b[rank],MPI_FLOAT,b,send_count_b,disp_b,MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

please help me out.

Comment: You are using floor()'ed and ceil()'ed double's to determine rowcounts, bases, indices and sizes. That is the FIRST thing i would fix. Instead of using float/double division to determine the slices of the matrix you should just divide integers by integers like in this example: `rowsA=rows/3; rowsB=rows/3; rowsC=rows-rowsA-rowsB;`.

Comment: I removed them(not just removed but adjusted the not divisible by p case),still the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that strikes me as odd is the scatter_data function prototype placed in a body of another function. That is quite unusual.

Second, it might be helpful to see the full code. Having full code to compile would help us do some home debugging as MPI code is generally pretty hard to debug on the screen.

EDIT ::

I did clean your code a little bit and added some comments and checks. Both scatterv and gatherv seem to work just fine - I added another array (C) that is used to store gathered data as opposed to the original A array that contains the same data *before* and *after* the two MPI calls. I also modified the size of local temp arrays used for the scattered data.

One thing that could be confusing you is the size of the receive buffer that is used for scattered data. The original code used too much space and gave me seg faults when I incremented received data. For example, for a 4x4 A matrix the original receive buffer size was 8x4 but should have been 2x4 assuming two processes. Your `SIZE_B(n,size)` function actually returns the right number.

```
#define NUM_EQN 4

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int size,rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(  MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    float *A = malloc(sizeof(float)*NUM_EQN*NUM_EQN);
    float *b = malloc(sizeof(float)*NUM_EQN);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_EQN * NUM_EQN; i++) A[i] = (float)i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_EQN; i++) b[i] = (float)i;

    gather(A,b,NUM_EQN);

    MPI_Finalize();
    printf("End of process %d\n",rank);
}
```

and

```
void gather(float *A,float *b,int n){

    int i, j;
    int size,rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(  MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    float *A_recv,*b_recv;
    A_recv = malloc(sizeof(float)*(SIZE_A(n,size)));
    b_recv = malloc(sizeof(float)*(SIZE_B(n,size)));    // size A and B are probably the array parts located in current thread
    float *C = malloc(sizeof(float)*NUM_EQN*NUM_EQN);

    printf("n: %d %d %d \n",n,SIZE_A(n,size),SIZE_B(n,size));

    if ( rank == 0 )
    {
        print_array(A,b,n);
    }
    int send_count[size];
    int disp[size];
    int send_count_b[size];
    int disp_b[size];
    for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        send_count[i] = 0 ;
        send_count_b[i] = 0;
    }
    for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        send_count[i] = n*NUM_ROWS(i,n,size);
        if ( i == 0 )
                disp[i] = 0;
        else
                disp[i] = disp[i-1] + send_count[i-1];
        send_count_b[i] = NUM_ROWS(i,n,size);
        if ( i == 0 )
                disp_b[i] = 0 ;
        else
                disp_b[i] = disp_b[i-1] + send_count_b[i-1];

        printf("%d Displacement[%d] : %d Sendcount : %d \n", rank, i, disp[i], send_count[i]);
    }


    MPI_Scatterv(A, send_count, disp ,MPI_FLOAT, A_recv,SIZE_A(n,size),MPI_FLOAT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    /*
    int MPI_Scatterv( void *sendbuf, int *sendcnts, int *displs,
                 MPI_Datatype sendtype, void *recvbuf, int recvcnt,
                 MPI_Datatype recvtype,
                 int root, MPI_Comm comm)*/

    //MPI_Scatterv(b, send_count_b, disp_b,MPI_FLOAT, b_recv,send_count_b[rank], MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("%d Receive data : \n",rank);
    for ( i = 0 ; i < SIZE_B(n,size); i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
        {
            A_recv[i*n+j] = A_recv[i*n+j] + 10.0;
            printf("%d %3.2f : ",rank, A_recv[i*n+j]);

        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        printf("%d Gather data : \n",rank);
        for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
                printf("%d %3.2f : ",rank, C[i*n+j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    MPI_Gatherv(A_recv,SIZE_A(n,size),MPI_FLOAT,C,send_count,disp,MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        printf("%d Gather data : \n",rank);
        for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf("%d", rank);
            for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
                printf(" %3.2f : ",C[i*n+j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    //MPI_Gatherv(b_recv,send_count_b[rank],MPI_FLOAT,b,send_count_b,disp_b,MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

As you can see, I did get rid of the b array since that uses pretty much the same code.

The matrix C is displayed before and after the MPI_gather call (for -np 2 ) and it would seem that the originally scattered data are now successfully gathered - I just add 10 to each scattered number to verify that the new modified data are properly gathered.

For -np = 2 and for -np = 4 as well.

```
0 Gather data BEFORE MPI CALL: 
0 -0.00 : 0 -0.00 : 0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 
0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 
0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 
0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 0 0.00 : 
0 Gather data AFTER MPI CALL: 
0 10.00 :  11.00 :  12.00 :  13.00 : 
0 14.00 :  15.00 :  16.00 :  17.00 : 
0 18.00 :  19.00 :  20.00 :  21.00 : 
0 22.00 :  23.00 :  24.00 :  25.00 :
```

Also, I have found a nice example of MPI_Scatterv located here : https://gist.github.com/ehamberg/1263868

Another nice example is here :
https://rqchp.ca/modules/cms/checkFileAccess.php?file=local.rqchpweb_udes/mpi/exemples_c/ex07_Scatter_EN.c

And one more suggestion :: it is a good habit to `free()` your dynamically allocated variables.

Comment: 1) You seem to scatter flattened matrix A and array b to A_recv and b_recv in multiple processes. I believe the A_recv is oversized -- for example, for A = 4x4 and 2 processes its size should be 4x2 (the code seems to generate 8x2).

Comment: 2) I have cleaned your code and modified it a little bit and did not find anything wrong with it. I have edited my answer above.